# Create a VS 2017 extension to add new code file

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.  I have two separate piece of code that functions outside of Visual Studio.

The last step performed by the second piece of code currently creates a new c# source file.  I would like to combine both pieces of code into a single VSIX extension.

Unfortunately I have never worked with VS Extensions and I am a bit lost.  I have worked through various VSIX examples, but none of these create files.

Can anyone perhaps point me to a working example of how to add new source files to a project via an extension?

I have seen some examples, but they all refer to old Add-In style plugins and not VSIX.

Answer (score 1):

> Create a VS 2017 extension to add new code file

As we know the [Visual Studio Extensions](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/features/extend/) is:

> Extensions are add-ons that allow you to customize and enhance your
>   experience in Visual Studio by adding new features or integrating
>   existing tools. An extension can range in all levels of complexity,
>   but its main purpose is to increase your productivity and cater to
>   your workflow.

So, the Visual Studio extension is service for **Visual Studio IDE** to customize and enhance your experience in Visual Studio, rather than serving a specific project.

What I suspect the [Project and item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2017) should be helps.

Hope this helps.